# How to add sleep or wait for JS using JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add sleep from this function ShowSC()

```
function ShowSC(){
 $("#SC").html('LOADING');
 //adding the sleep 1 second
 $("#SC").html('<img src="secure/captcha/securimage_show.php" class="img_middle" />');
}
```

ADVANCE THANKS!

Sorry, I can't find a solution from other question so I just start a question here.

Comment: You must be kidding `:)` one cannot miss setTimeout() function when dealing with javascript !

Comment: ONE DOES NOT SIMPLY PAUSE JAVASCRIPT :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I do if I want a JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: @Cracker0dks you're damn right, Javascript pauses you !

Comment: Just to clarify, if your intention is to freeze the code for 1 second, and then continue in the same function, A) Javascript will probably fight you all of the way and it won't be easy, B) Your UI experience will be very annoying. setTimeout is fine to use; I just want to make sure you realize it works differently from how Thread.sleep() might in other languages.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `setTimeout`, it executes a function, once, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds

```
function ShowSC(){
     $("#SC").html('LOADING');

     //adding the sleep 1 second
     setTimeout(function(){
        $("#SC").html('<img src="secure/captcha/securimage_show.php" class="img_middle" />');
     }, 1000);
}
```

Here `1000` is in milliseconds

Comment: I thought this is very hard.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Way™ is to use [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```
$('#SC')
    .html('LOADING')
    .delay(1000)
    .queue(function (n) {
        $(this).html('<img src="secure/captcha/securimage_show.php" class="img_middle" />');
        n();
    });
```

It helps maintain chainable code, which can tend to be more readable. Readable code is easier to maintain and extend.

The vanilla JavaScript way is to use a callback in [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout):

```
$('#SC').html('LOADING');
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#SC').html('<img src="secure/captcha/securimage_show.php" class="img_middle" />');
}, 1000);
```

Chaining `setTimeout` calls within `setTimeout` calls can end up with callback [arrow code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html), so I generally recommend making use of queueing even if you're not using jQuery. You'd want to make use of some sort of queueing.

<sub>The following example makes use of a [`Queue`](https://github.com/zzzzBov/jsoop/blob/master/Queue.js) class that I wrote:</sub>

```
(function () {
    var sc,
        q;
    q = new Queue();
    sc = document.getElementById('SC');
    sc.innerHTML = 'LOADING';
    q.queue(function (n) {
        setTimeout(n, 1000);
    },function (n) {
        sc.innerHTML = '<img src="secure/captcha/securimage_show.php" class="img_middle" />';
        n();
    });
}());
```

Comment: thanks for helping me, brother. I have picked lot of learnings from you. ^_^ you are friendly and interested to help more people.